# Append dict into another dictionary?

Tags: python

I have code as mentioned below.

```
a={'test': { 'test':'Test2','scale':'scale4'},
   'test2': {'test':'test5','scale':'scale44'},
   'test3': { 'test':'Test2','scale':'scale4'}}

dict1={}
blue_print={}

for i,v in a.items():
   blue_print['scale']=a[i].get('scale')
   blue_print['test'] =a[i].get('test')
dict1.update(blue_print)
print(dict1)
```

The above showing the output only:

```
{'scale': 'scale4', 'test': 'Test2'}
```

I want the output should displayed like below:

```
{{'scale': 'scale4', 'test': 'Test2'},
 {'scale': 'scale44', 'test': 'test5'},
 {'scale': 'scale4', 'test': 'Test2'}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression (taking union of dictionaries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-taking-union-of-dictiona)

Comment: The expected output you showed isn't a valid dictionary, though. Dictionaries _cannot_ have duplicate keys, so each line like `blue_print['scale']=a[i].get('scale')` in a loop _overwrites_ the previous values of `blue_print['scale']`, so when you do `dict1.update(blue_print)`, `blue_print` will contain data from the _last_ iteration only

Comment: Dictionaries also cannot be placed into sets. Did you want to use a list?

Comment: The provided "dictionary" at the end doesn't actually have any keys, it's just a list of objects.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a list of the values in the input dict, not merging anything (which you don't want because each test/scale key would get overriden, as you've found out)

```
>>> a={'test': { 'test':'Test2','scale':'scale4'},'test2':{'test':'test5','scale':'scale44'},'test3': { 'test':'Test2','scale':'scale4'}}
>>> [v for _, v in a.items()]
[{'test': 'Test2', 'scale': 'scale4'}, {'test': 'test5', 'scale': 'scale44'}, {'test': 'Test2', 'scale': 'scale4'}]
```

Or `list(a.values())`

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = list(a.values())
```

```
>>> print(dict1)
[{'test': 'Test2', 'scale': 'scale4'}, {'test': 'test5', 'scale': 'scale44'}, {'test': 'Test2', 'scale': 'scale4'}]
```